# how do I retrive a text, from a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textfield

this is the code. which create a GUI.

I need to make a function that works if I press the button

```
package View;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import modulo.Test;

public class InterfacciaGrafica extends JFrame  implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public InterfacciaGrafica(String ArrayClienti[]){
        this.setTitle("BiKar Prenotazioni");
        this.setSize( 300,200);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setForeground(Color.black);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
          
        PannelloIscrizione PannelloIscrizione = new PannelloIscrizione(ArrayClienti);
        this.add(PannelloIscrizione,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        PannelloIscrizione.setVisible(true);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    
}
```

```
package View;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import modulo.PatenteTypes;
public class PannelloIscrizione extends JPanel  implements ActionListener{
    
    private static final AbstractButton ID = null;
    Color Arancione = new Color(255, 175, 0);
    int eta;
    String nome;
    String cognome;
    String id;
    String tipoPatente;
    String tipoCliente;
    
    public PannelloIscrizione(String ArrayClienti[]) {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setForeground(Color.orange);
        
        Container ContainerCentro = new Container();
        ContainerCentro.setSize(200, 100);
        
        JComboBox TipoCliente = new JComboBox(ArrayClienti);
        JTextField Nome = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField Cognome = new JTextField(20);
        JTextArea ID = new JTextArea(id);
        JTextField Eta = new JTextField(2);
        JComboBox<PatenteTypes> TipoPatente= new JComboBox<PatenteTypes>(PatenteTypes.values());
        JButton Iscrizione = new JButton("Iscriviti");
        
        ContainerCentro.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
        this.add(ContainerCentro, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        ContainerCentro.setBackground(Color.black);
        ContainerCentro.setForeground(Color.black);
        
        ContainerCentro.add(ID,BorderLayout.WEST);
        ContainerCentro.add(Eta, BorderLayout.EAST);
        ContainerCentro.add(TipoPatente,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ID.setBackground(Arancione);
        ID.setForeground(Color.black);
        Eta.setBackground(Arancione);
        Eta.setForeground(Color.black);
        TipoPatente.setBackground(Arancione);
        TipoPatente.setForeground(Color.black);
        
        Container ContainerNord = new Container();
        ContainerNord.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(ContainerNord, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        ContainerNord.setSize(200, 100);
        ContainerNord.add(TipoCliente,BorderLayout.WEST);
        ContainerNord.add(Nome, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ContainerNord.add(Cognome, BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        ContainerNord.setBackground(Color.black);
        ContainerNord.setForeground(Color.black);
        TipoCliente.setBackground(Arancione);
        TipoCliente.setForeground(Color.black);
        Nome.setBackground(Arancione);
        Nome.setForeground(Color.black);
        Cognome.setBackground(Arancione);
        Cognome.setForeground(Color.black);

        Container ContainerSud = new Container();
        ContainerSud.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(ContainerSud, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        ContainerSud.setBackground(Color.black);
        ContainerSud.setForeground(Color.black);
        ContainerSud.add(Iscrizione, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Iscrizione.setBackground(Arancione);
        Iscrizione.setForeground(Color.black);
        
        
    
        
    
        ContainerCentro.setVisible(true);
        ContainerNord.setVisible(true);
        ContainerSud.setVisible(true);
        TipoCliente.setVisible(true);
        ID.setVisible(true);
        Eta.setVisible(true);
        TipoPatente.setVisible(true);
        Nome.setVisible(false);
        Cognome.setVisible(false);
        Iscrizione.setVisible(true);
        
    
        Iscrizione.addActionListener(this);
       

    
}
    public int getEta() {
        return eta;
    }
    public void setEta(int eta) {
        this.eta = eta;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }
    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTipoPatente() {
        return tipoPatente;
    }
    public void setTipoPatente(String tipoPatente) {
        this.tipoPatente = tipoPatente;
    }
    public String getTipoCliente() {
        return tipoCliente;
    }
    public void setTipoCliente(String tipoCliente) {
        this.tipoCliente = tipoCliente;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(Iscrizione)) {
            
            setId(ID.getText());
            System.out.println(ID.getText());
        }
    }

}
```

i want to write some text in the JTextField from my GUI, then once the button in clicked, I want the text to become the value of the attribute id of my class. but getText doesn't work

The first class declare my Frame, inside of it there is a Panel that contains a few text field.

Comment: Since you've not provided a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue (or even a code snippet which would actually compile), I'm forced to guess that `ID` is declared locally to the context of the constructor, making it inaccessible to the `actionPerformed` method.  If that's the case then, `ID` should be made an instance field instead

Comment: Yes, `.getText()` is how you extract text from a JTextField. That it doesn't work suggests that you've got a bug in your code somewhere, likely within this code: *"i omitted all the less relevant parts of the code, but I will add them if necessary."*.  I suggest that you show more code, specifically a [mre] -- please read the link to see *exactly* what this is and why it can help you and us.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: (1-) 1)  In your last question it was also suggested that variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. These conventions are used in every text book or tutorial I have ever seen.  We should NOT have to repeat suggestions. Our time can be better spent helping others. 2) In this example you are using "setSize()`. The tutorial link you were also given yesterday contains plenty of examples. None of them use that method. It is the job of the layout managers. Learn by example or you will continue to have basic problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(e.getSource().equals("Iscrizione")) {
        //setId(ID.getText());
    }
```

This is always going to be false. e.getSource() returns a Component and Component.equals(String) will always be false;